# Which Layout(s) Should I Use?

Tags: android, layout, grid, frame

I am building a calculator app and I have the images for all the buttons. I also have a single image that I want to use for the calculator background.

Here is a simple example of what I have:

Buttons (all individual images):
[image]

Background (single image):
[image]

Desired Appearance:
[image]

What layout(s) would I use to place a grid of images (the buttons) on top of a single image. GridLayout over FrameLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with

```
<LinearLayout android:background="..." android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout><LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout><LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout><LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

add appropriate `android:layout_weight` values and you are done.

I wouldn't use `GridLayout` or something since you don't have a dynamic layout at all. It is all static and will never change...

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout android:background="....">
```

...

Comment: ah i see you added the background attribute. thanks!

Comment: aha :) I editted it! check again @JanTacci

Comment: Generally you can stack multiple items in FrameLayout.